# PayPal webhook events never being sent?

Tags: paypal, webhooks, paypal-webhooks

We have a production game that uses PayPal as one of the methods of payment. In some cases, we're never receiving webhook notifications.

Here's the sequence that's occurring. Sometimes we get the webhook from this sequence, and other times we don't. On the server, we're using the Java API. All of this is the behavior with the production (NOT SANDBOX) PayPal servers.

1. After the user selects a product, it calls our server, which creates the Payment object via Payment.create(). At that point the state is 'created' and we redirect the user to the approval_url returned in the links.
2. The user approves the payment and is sent back to our server. We fetch the payment via Payment.get(), which is successful and has a state of 'created'.
3. We execute the payment using a PaymentExecution. This returns the payment with an updated state of "approved".
4. We then wait for a WebHook to inform us that the payment was completed. On occasion, this webhook is never sent, leaving the purchase incomplete. Checking the PayPal console, no webhook event exists for the payment, even though the payment is showing up as completed.

The questions here are:

- Is this the correct sequence? Or is something missing?
- Shouldn't the payment be "approved" when the user is returned from PayPal rather than still "created"?
- Shouldn't the payment be either "completed" or "in_progress" after a successful execute?
- What is the correct way to handle the case where the webhook never arrives? Keep polling the payment until the state updates?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any problem with your sequence. You can also refer to the steps here as an example - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/

Regarding Webhooks, you mentioned sometimes you get Webhooks and only some times you do not. Can you please provide a correlation or debug id for the calls where you don't see any Webhook? We will trouble shoot and get back?

Comment: The missing webhook call was reported as Incident 160508-000086.